# Excel: Find unique values from a row and create a column for it?

Tags: excel, unique, rows

I am not sure if we can do this in excel. I have a spreadsheetA of about 1000 rows like this:

```
Col 1      Col 2  
Fruit1      (Apple, Banana, Grape, Orange)  
Fruit2      (Apple, Orange)  
Fruit3     (Grape, Banana, Orange)  
Fruit4     (Pineapple)
```

What I want to do? This:

```
Col1        Apple Banana Grape Orange Pineapple  
Fruit1      yes   yes    yes   yes    no  
Fruit2      yes   no     no    yes    no  
Fruit3      no    yes    yes   yes    no  
Fruit4      no    no     no    no     yes
```

Problem: Column 2 has fruit names. Find unique fruit names first for each row and create a column based on unique values found. Also, if the value repeats, add yes/no for the respective row in which the value was found again. So I need to split values into column and have a counter for each time value repeats. I have to create spreadsheetB from spreadsheetA. In the example, Apple, Banana, Grape, Orange and Pineapple became unique column names and I checked yes or no for each row if the value was found.

I need help in this, its been 2 days already but I could not come up with an excel solution. Python solution is easy but I cannot use programming.

I am very sorry, my format game is not strong on Stackoverflow.

Thanks! :)

Comment: do you want to write a c# program for it?

Comment: I'd answer this, but I don't think I could beat Scott to the answer...something about search/find formulas will be used

Comment: are you looking for a process or are you looking for formula?  For instance can you use the text-to-columns feature to split column two into multiple columns with a single word in each column?

Comment: The hard part is generating the unique list of words...what version of excel are you working with?

Comment: I am sorry, I am so bad in formatting. This needs to be done through Excel 2013. I  feel it cannot be done through formula, so process would be good to explore. Finding unique values and make columns in a new spreadsheet. Then go back to SheetA and use Vlookup to search rows and match in sheetB? Please enlighten me if you can find a better solution. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a maximum number or words in a cell?

Comment: No, in my current file it's ranging between 1 to 20.

Comment: does the fruit name list have actual () or was that just for the benefit of showing us that it was all in column 2?

Comment: It was just for the benefit of showing that its all in column 2. Thank you for working with me on this. I really appreciate all the help I am getting here. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner,  You got a 2013 way to better create the unique list of words for the column headers that does not use VBA since programing is not allowed?

Comment: @ForwardEd I could probably come up with an array formula that would do what is needed, but it would be overly complicated and very slow as it mined 1000 rows.  And to be honest no, I could not do it in 2013 as any chance would use TEXTJOIN() which is not available.  Your manual method is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel there is a way to do this with something like TXTSPLIT or regex, but I only have 2013 and apparently you do to so those will not be an option.

This is just a thought process off the top of my head.  I would start by copying the second column to the worksheet where you plan to have your table.  Then I would start in that work sheet by selecting your data, then selecting "Text to columns" in your ribbon.

[image: Text to Columns]

You should then wind up at this screen

[image: Screen 1]

Select the "Delimited" radio button and then press <kbd>Next</kbd>.

[image: Screen 2]

Make sure you select Comma as your delimiter, or whatever matches what is separating your words.  You may want to select "Treat consecutive delimiters as one" if you have gaps in you data such as Apple,,Brains, Beaver Tails.  Make sure you do not have space selected as a delimiter incase you have multi word data between your delimeters.

Your data should then be split into multiple columns with each word in its own cell.

[image: Results 1]

I would then select each individual column then choose the remove duplicates button.  I tried doing multiple columns at once but it did not remove duplicates in all columns when I did that.

So select your column(s)

[image: Duplicates 1]

Then select remove duplicates from the ribbon

[image: Duplicates 2]

I selected continue with selection as I only wanted to deal with one column at a time.

[image: Duplicates 3]

I left the "My data has headers" unchecked and hit ok

[image: Duplicates 4]

And voila we have a unique list in the column

[image: Duplicates 5]

Repeat this for all columns.  Then move your columns into one column and repeat the duplicate process.  You could have done this step first but it may have been longer columns to deal with moving around.  In the end you should wind up with one column of unique words.

Here all the columns are unique within the column but not the table.

[image: Duplicates 6]

So the columns get stacked into 1

[image: Duplicates 7]

And after running remove duplicates on the single column the following unique list is obtained.

[image: Duplicates 8]

Now you can take that data and transpose it to become your column headers and with a minor tweak you can make your table look like:

[image: Results table]

So now that we have our table setup, I would use the following formula in B2 of the table and copy down and right.  Note the $ to lock the row or column reference.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B$1,$B12)),"yes","no")
'FIND is case sensitive
```

Edit

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$B12)),"yes","no")
'SEARCH is NOT case sensitive
```

In the case of this formula, B$1 is your header row, and $B12 is the first row of column two with data.

Results look like the following based on the date being layed out in B12:b15

[image: POC]

### Formulaic alternative

place the following in the third column copy right and down as far as needed.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&$B2&REPT(",",6),",",REPT(" ",255)),COLUMNS($B2:B2)*255,255))
```

I personally would copy it over all the way to column z or so first, then down your 10K rows.

Now for the part that will bog your system down. THIS WILL BE A HUGE AMOUNT OF CALCULATIONS FOR EACH CELL THE FORMULA WINDS UP IN.  It will be generating the unique list.  Use the following in an unused column starting in the second row.  convert the range G12:J15 to match B2:Z10000 or whatever range you wound up with.  Change $L$11:L11 to empty space above where you want the first unique name to appear.  So if you wanted to start your list in AA2 change it to $AA$1:AA1.

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($G$12:$J$15<>"")*(COUNTIF($L$11:L11,$G$12:$J$15)=0),ROW($G$12:$J$15)*100+COLUMN($G$12:$J$15),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

This is an ARRAY formula or CSE.  It means you will need to use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when finishing the formula, not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when you see {} around your formula in the formula bar.  These cannot be added manually.  Copy the list down only as far as you need.  It will generate blank entries when there are no more unique entries, however its still performing a massive amount of calculations.

From there you can generate your header row by using the following formula, assuming you did all the above generation on Sheet1.  Use the following formula where you want your first header and copy right:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!AA:AA,COLUMN(B1))
```

Then you can generate your yes/no table like the formula used in the last step of the manual method.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this procedure on original file and see what happens. I will get back to you.

Comment: Locking in...Final Answer!

Comment: with a picture being worth a thousand words...that is at least a 14K word answer!

Comment: Got a formulaic method but it may be really slow with your data amounts

Comment: With my data, I was able to make a grid but the formula =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$B12)),"yes","no") is showing me wrong results. I tried multiple times different ways. I am really highly grateful for your help here. It's fantastic! I could not transpose column of unique values to make separate column so I did copy paste manually. Also, in the search formula, the search string is in another sheet, so should I use VLOOKUP?

Comment: I could not get time to try the "formulaic method" yet but I will shortly after I finish the "process method" you suggested. I am very much thankful to you :)